# Condition for a quotient space to be compact

Tags: group-theory, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, quaternions

[image]

I am thinking that: If we can find a compact set $K \subset SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $(\pi_3 \circ \pi_2 \circ \phi \circ \pi_1 )(K)=\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ then $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ is compact (by continuity of maps $\pi_3,\pi_2,\phi,\pi_1$, a compact set maps to a compact set). That is equivalent to  find a fixed compact set $K \subset SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that for every $g\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ there exist $\gamma \in \Gamma^1$ such that $\gamma.g\in K$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just want to ask if what I wrote is right or wrong. Because I am reading the proof of Theorem 5.4.1 in Katok's book, and Katok seemly made the proof to be more complicated when she said that the theorem follows from Corollary 3.6.2 at the end.

Comment: What does it mean for a subgroup of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ to be "symmetric"?

Comment: It means that $-g\in \Gamma^1$ for every $g\in  \Gamma^1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find a compact subset $K \subset \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ so that the map from $K$ to $\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}$ is surjective, then you can find another compact subset $K' \subset \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ so that the second condition holds. To construct $K'$, you will need the fact that every point pre-image of the map $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}$ is compact, being homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \text{(two points)}$. I will refer to these point pre-images as "fibers". Then you simply take $K'$ to be the union of $K$ with each fiber that has nonempty intersection with $K$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. So now we can claim that: the first condition $\Leftrightarrow$ the second condition. I want to ask you one more question: Suppose that $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ is compact, in which conditions we can find a compact set $K\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that the map from $K$ to $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ is surjective ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest condition is simply that $\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}$ is compact.